# Adding QtSoap Reference to Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt

i have built the dll its QtSolutions_SOAP-2.7d.dll and now i want to reference that in Qt Creator how do i do that ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the QtSolutions package you also have an examples directory with several examples.
Basically you just have to include src/qtsoap.pri in the .pro file of your project.
And the dll should be in your PATH.